# Default Superclass in Java

Tags: java

I was reading an article on [Inheritance](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inheritance-in-java/) . Few facts were listed on Inheritance but one point i couldn't understand what is Default superclass and its explanation. What is Default superclass?

**Default Superclass** : Except Object class, which has no superClass, every class has one and only one direct superclass(single inheritance). In the absence of any other explicit superclass, every class is implicitly a subclass of the Object class.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you do not understand from the quoted text? It clearly has the answer to your question.

Comment: It's literally in that quote: `every class is implicitly a subclass of the Object class` ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *default superclass* is `Object` (more precisely `java.lang.Object`). If a class does not define a direct superclass explicitly (via `extends`), then `Object` is implicitly a superclass of that class.

Have a look at the following example which graphically shows this:

```java
public class A {}
public class B extends A {}
public class C {}
```

[image: diagram]

Note that his rule does not apply to `Object` itself since this would produce a cyclic inheritance. In other words, `java.lang.Object` is the root of the class hierarchy.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This Visual representation really helped me.

Answer (score 2):

**Except Object class, which has no Super Class, every class has one and only one direct superclass(single inheritance). In the absence of any other explicit superclass, every class is implicitly a subclass of the Object class**

Points to understand first:

1. There is a class **Object** in java which is already available with the JRE libraries.
2. When you define a class without an extends keyword, your class will by default extend the **Object** class in Java.
3. Even if you extend another class in your new class, the parent or its parent transitively inherits the Object class.

Simple way to understand - after you define a class with / without a parent class, create an object for it. If you are using an IDE, you can see that there are some method suggestions which is not implemented in your class (or parent ). Methods like `clone()` `equals()` `hashCode()` `wait()` etc. Where did these methods/ behaviors come from to your object ? - Yes it came from the ultimate parent **Object**

The default inheritance is implicit and handled by the Java itself. Hope this makes your understanding better.

Answer (score 1):

object class is **base class** for every class you create.
when you create an object of your class then constructor of object class is called.

Answer (score 1):

The Object class in Java is the default superclass. Object class is inherited into a newly created class by default if it does not explicitly inherited from any other class. So every class that you create in Java programming is inherently a child class of the Object.

Answer (score 0):

All classes in Java extend `Object` class by default, and they are subclass of object class, the only exception of this convention is the `Object` class itself, object class does not extend any class by default, this is the whole idea.